Creating a DBT Model for Messenger Data Integration
I am creating a DBT Model for the first time and need some assistance. I need to add these columns to my MODEL (MESSENGER_ID, MESSENGER_DEPT, MESSAGE_TYPE_ID, MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME) from MESSENGER TABLE satisfying this condition "MESSAGE_TYPE_ID = 'ABC123-DEF456-GHI789' AND MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME LIKE '%TEXT%'".
Similarly I also need to add other set of columns to the same DBT Model (MESSENGER_ID_2, MESSENGER_DEPT_2) but to retrieve this data a link should be established between two tables (Admin & Messenger) ADMIN.ADMIN_DEPT_ID = MESSENGER.ID and also it should satisfy this condition "MESSAGE_TYPE_ID = 'X1Y2Z3-4A5B6C-7D8E9F' AND MESSAAGE_TYPE_NAME LIKE '%TEXT%'".
Any assistance will be appreciated.
MESSENGER:
    ID
    DEPT
    MESSAGE_TYPE_ID
    MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME

ADMIN:
    ID
    RESOURCE_ID
    ADMIN_DEPT_ID

I have come up with the below but need some advices on best practices
SELECT 
    m.ID AS MESSENGER_ID,
    m.DEPT AS MESSENGER_DEPT,
    m.MESSAGE_TYPE_ID AS MESSAGE_TYPE_ID,
    m.MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME AS MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME,
    a.ADMIN_DEPT_ID AS MESSENGER_ID_2,
    m2.MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME AS MESSENGER_TYPE_NAME_2
FROM 
    {{source('BULK_MESSENGER_DEV','MESSENGER')}} m
LEFT JOIN 
    {{source('BULK_MESSENGER_DEV','ADMIN')}} a
ON 
    a.ADMIN_DEPT_ID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    {{source('BULK_MESSENGER_DEV','MESSENGER')}} m2
ON 
    m2.ID = a.ADMIN_DEPT_ID
WHERE 
    (m.MESSAGE_TYPE_ID = 'ABC123-DEF456-GHI789' AND (m.MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME) LIKE '%TEXT%')
    OR (m2.MESSAGE_TYPE_ID = 'X1Y2Z3-4A5B6C-7D8E9F' AND (m2.MESSAAGE_TYPE_NAME) LIKE '%TEXT%')


A good starting point is dbt docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/best-practices
